# How to remove latitude and longitude (they're constants) from variables in netcdf dataset using xarray?

Tags: python, variables, dataset, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a NetCDF data set I am trying to remove latitude and longitude data from my data variables so they can be indexed properly. The shape of each data variable is always (x, 1, 1) with x being my number of data points and the 1's representing the static longitude and latitudes. I've tried `xarray.Dataset.squeeze` and `xarray.Dataset.drop` and `xarray.DataArray.drop_vars` targeting latitude and longitude. I also tried it with a pandas data frame and the latitude and longitudes still stay glued to my variables and prevent indexing properly. If you copy my code below you will see the variable `'wave_height'` shows a shape of (3411,1,1). I want a function that makes this shape just (3411,).

```
url = 'https://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/fileServer/data/stdmet/46077/46077h2021.nc'
reqSpectra = urllib.request.Request(url)
with urllib.request.urlopen(reqSpectra) as respS:
    ds_s = xr.open_dataset(io.BytesIO(respS.read()))

wh = ds_s.variables['wave_height']
wh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use NumPy's squeeze to remove extra dimensions.

```
import urllib
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import io
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
url = 'https://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/fileServer/data/stdmet/46077/46077h2021.nc'
reqSpectra = urllib.request.Request(url)
with urllib.request.urlopen(reqSpectra) as respS:
    ds_s = xr.open_dataset(io.BytesIO(respS.read()))
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
wh = ds_s.variables['wave_height'];
wh = np.squeeze(wh);
wh
```